# JavaScript regex to match optional decimal numbers with optional metric identifier

Tags: javascript, regex

I have managed to get this far with my regex:

```
/^(\+|\-|\/)*\d+?([kbmt]{1}|.\d{1,2})?$/gmi
```

It matches these numbers:

`9`
`90`
`90.00`
`90.99`
`90k`

`+9`
`-90`
`+90.00`
`-90.99`
`+90k`

`+/-9`
`+/-90`
`+/-90.00`
`+/-90.99`
`+/-90k`

But I want it to match these, too:

`90.00k`
`90.99k`
`-90.00k`
`+90.99k`
`+/-90.00k`
`+/-90.99k`

How do I sweep up the remaining numbers that need to be matched?

Here's a fiddle: https://regex101.com/r/jD9bH3/1

Comment: You want to be careful with the formatting of your posts here.  By not applying any to the regex, you changed its meaning and made it syntactically invalid.  You also combined some of your number samples, so `9` and `90` became `9 90`, for example.  I know it's annoying that you *have* to use formatting on certain things to make them legible, but the benefits are worth it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This matches every example you gave:

```
/^(?:[+-]|\+\/\-)?\d+(?:\.\d+)?[kbmt]?$/gim
```

It won't match `+++2` or `+-+-+-2` or `+/--/+2` and etc. Also, I used non-capturing subgroups where groups were necessary as I don't believe you care about getting back the parts in the parens by themselves.

Demo and explanation breakdown: https://regex101.com/r/oP6cB4/2

Comment: Almost exactly what I was going to suggest!   It corrects all the major mistakes, but shouldn't `[kbmt]` be `[kmgt]` (kilo, mega, giga, tera)?

Comment: Also, your fiddle at Regex101 has the PCRE flavor selected instead of JavaScript (the OP did that, too), and you left the `i` modifier off.

Comment: @AlanMoore - Thanks--I've updated the "fiddle" and the link in my answer. Not sure how I dropped the `i`. I had noticed it was PCRE too, and left it alone, but since the post is tagged JS I've gone ahead and changed it.

Comment: It's units of money as specified by the client.  K for thousand, M for millions, B for billions, T for trillions

Comment: @RyanP13: Okay, thanks for setting me straight.  I had the impression theses were dollar amounts, but if that's true, changing `\d{1,2}` in the decimal portion to `\.\d+` was probably incorrect, wasn't it?

Comment: Agreed--the question left that very unclear and I assumed the OP was being overly strict with the count limiters. If the numbers repesent USD amounts, the portion after the decimal should have a count limiter. Technically, it should require 2, as opposed to allowing for 1 or 2...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
^(\+|\-|\/)*\d+(\.\d{1,2})?[kbmt]?$
```

Also, you may want to be more specific at the beginning with the symbols so you don't match things like

```
+++2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:  `\+?-?\/?9{0,2}0{0,1}\.?\k?`

It gets all the strings in your example, but may need some tweaking if you have different numbers.

Edit with all the numbers & metric identifiers:  `\+?-?\/?\d{0,2}\d{0,1}\.?[kmbt]?`

Comment: Yes, sorry the numbers can be any.  I just used 9 for the examples.  My mistake!

Comment: Check my edit, it should take care of that as well as the metric identifiers.

Comment: This answer still has major problems.  In one example,  `\+?-?\/?` correctly matches `+` or `-`,  but not `+/-`; and it also matches several invalid prefixes (`+-/`, `+-`, -/`, `+/` and `/`).